# Changing input from composite to s video directshow

Tags: video, directshow, capture

I have a pinnancle video capture device and  I wrote a DirectShow based application which works well by composite input but with  S_Video First  there is nothing to show through S_Video input (although in trace I see everything is ok!) till I run pinnacle studio. after that everything goes well!The next problem is switching between S_Video and Composite. If I change the input from S_Video to Composite, It  won't show anything.I'm wondering what is different between S_Video and Video(Composite)and pinnancle sutdio how  affects the capturing after closing;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change inputs using `IAMCrossbar::Route`, see [Working with Crossbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details. Note that you can also do it interactively with GraphEdit, through crossbar filter property page:

[image]

Comment: this solution worked for grapheditt  but  after calling this code   
**IAMCrossbar *pXBar1 = NULL; 
hr = pBuild->FindInterface(&LOOK_UPSTREAM_ONLY, NULL, pSrc, 
IID_IAMCrossbar, (void**)&pXBar1);** return E_FAIL

Comment: Windows SDK comes with `AMCap` sample which shows how to do it right, in particular it make crossbar property page available via menu command.

Comment: thanks.but Amcap also return E_FAil  unfortunately,  in this code :amcap.cpp  line:1193 **' hr =  gcap.pBuilder->FindInterface(&LOOK_UPSTREAM_ONLY, NULL, pf,
   IID_IAMCrossbar, (void**)&pXBar1); '**

Comment: AMCap should be working, it is a sort of a "reference application". If it does now, the reason is unclear and might perhaps be a bad driver. You will need to get in touch with hardware vendor to clear this up.

Comment: if it is driver issue why graphedt.exe work well?.I am totally Confused,we test on 2 PC but result is the same .